# How can I customize(css) field in template? (forms.IntegerField)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a trouble. I have *form*:

```
from django import forms


class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, initial=1)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

How I can customize(css) this field in template?
I try do it by widget, but just broken form, lol.

Help me pls, I feel me retarded.

Comment: Customize? Are you asking to customize the css?

Comment: Yeah, mean customize css. Fix it in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) lets u to customize your form in your template
Example :

```
{% for field in form %}
{% render_field field class="form-control" value="" %}
{% endfor %}
```